# Angular UI modal POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load angular-ui modal but I can't find any information how to pass POST parameters to specified **templateUrl** url?

```
    var options = {
        controller: 'ModalInstance',
        backdrop: true,
        scope: $scope,
        size: ( typeof $element.data('size') != 'undefined' ) ? $element.data('size') : 'sm',
        backdropClass: backdrop,
        templateUrl: 'some url',
        data: { // needs to be replaced | this one is not working.
            media_id: 59 
        },
        resolve: {
            element: function(){
                return $element;
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.instance = $modal.open( options );
```

If there is no any official ways, how can I do it without get parameters?

Comment: That is what resolve is for, sending data to be consumed by the `ModalInstance` controller. The templateUrl tells angular to load up a template

Comment: So you say that, i can't load template with specified params to load other content?

Comment: What other content did you want to load? I don't think you quite understand the process

Comment: I have *.php file where I'm loading different layout depends on media_id, so I need to push some params to get required results.

Comment: What you would do is query that php file first, then load the correct template into the modal instance. OR, you load the basic template into the modal instance, show the modal, get the controller to query the php file and change the content using `ng-include`.

Comment: Can you post how the PHP file makes a difference to the loaded template?

Comment: @CallumLinington i'm trying to avoid double load, so I don't use ng-include.

Php is simple: i check is there are parameter $media_id and then

after some work: 50lines of ~code... :)

return $objOutput->fetch( $required_template );

Comment: Yeah so do this before you load up the template. `ng-include` will look for a template in your `$templateCache` if it isn't there it will make the request. So in your `.run(function () {})` you can make the request for the templates there this will prevent them having to be loaded later in your app.

Comment: Use `$templateRequest` to get a template, you can pass an option config object `{ cache: true }` to state to it to look in cache as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation mentioned here [angular-ui directive documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

> templateUrl - a path to a template representing modal's content

which means it should be the url to a html file or  `<script type="text/ng-template">` which would be rendered as the content for modal window.

In case you want to pass some data to this template, refer the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) example the documentation provides.

The relevant things to be noted in this example for passing data to modal template are explained below

```
controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
size: size,
 resolve: {
        items: function () {
         return $scope.items;
        }
      }
```

1)controller : controller property specifies the name of the controller that controls the template(html to be rendered)
2)resolve: resolve property specifies the data that has to be injected into the
above controller

So in the example the ModalInstanceCtrl is the controller that is in control of the template to be rendered and items property can be injected into this controller, in other words you can pass the data to the modal window template.